# Home Renovation Tax Credit (HRTC) - Can I still claim it even if I pay cash?

Tags: canada, income-tax, home-renovation, tax-credit, cash

Can I still claim the Home Renovation Tax Credit even if I pay cash?

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can.  Let's hope you paid your share of sales taxes and kept the receipt.

Comment: +1.  Fair to say the government doesn't want to support the "underground economy" :-)